# Curvature due to changes in surface tension

Tags: fluid-dynamics, curvature, surface-tension

What happens to curvature of a surface when the surface tension starts to decrease?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on other parts of the scenario, perhaps. Maybe you provide more info?

According to the [Young-Laplace equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young%E2%80%93Laplace_equation) the pressure difference across the surface is the product of the surface tension and the mean curvature.

Let's say we suddenly decrease the surface tension of a soap bubble. The pressure difference caused by the surface tension no longer compensates the pressure difference of the gas inside and outside the bubble. The bubble thus expands until it either settles at a larger radius (and thus lower curvature) (because the expansion lowers the pressure inside) or bursts.

Answer (score 1):

For a solid shell equilibrium consideration gives

$$\frac { N_1}{R_1}+\frac{N_2}{R_2}= p$$

where N are stropic ress resultants and R are principal radii, reciprocal of curvatures $\kappa$. For an isotropic film

$$ N_1=N_2= N = \gamma,\; \text{the surface tension and mean curvature $H$} $$

$$ 2H= {\kappa_1}+ {\kappa_2 }= \frac{p}{\gamma} ;$$

There are three parameters to consider. Thus if surface tension and pressure are proportional, i.e.,  if they are increased by the same multiple, the shape of soap bubble does not change.

For same differential pressure across bubble wall  ( with large vessel size compared to bubble size) when surface tension is reduced, $ H$ is increased with a shape change. For symmetrical case with circular opening (through which pressure applied) a spherical bubble grows bigger.

For non symmetrical (e.g., elliptical ) openings,  $\kappa_1$ increases and $\kappa_2$ decreases for same pressure and a partial differential equation should be solved for doubly curved  bubble shapes $  {\kappa_1}\ne {\kappa_2}$.

Constant $H$ films of revolution for example have maximum volume for given surface area.